# Hdd Serial Number

Tags: c#, hard-drive

How  To Get The Serial Number  for all type of harddisk in c#.net

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242480/what-are-the-ways-to-obtain-hdd-serial-number-without-wmi

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/hard_disk_serialno.aspx) should help

It uses the WMI [Win32_PhysicalMedia](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394346(VS.85).aspx) class.

Answer (score 0):

S.M.A.R.T. IOCTL. Can't remember off the top of my head which smart command but basically you open the volume and issue a S.M.A.R.T. command...

Answer (score 0):

you can easily use [Hardware.Info](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hardware.Info/10.0.1?_src=template).

Code sample here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73628380/1546137