# How to retrieve HDD Firmware Serial number in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How can I retrieve HDD Firmware Serial number in .net?  I am able to retrieve HDD Serial number using WMI calls but not able to find any way to retrieve HDD Firmware Serial number.

Thanx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hdd Serial Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677251/hdd-serial-number)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176887/ , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242480/

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI. SImply as that - this is a low level function that no "sane" higher level API will support (it is useless to read or write files). WMI is made exactly for that - managing the lower levels.

Comment: This is a really vague answer without an example or specific WMI information related to the question.